# Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException trying yo insert using table inheritance on doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to insrt new data on this tables (using inheritance):

```
Entity\AbstractSurveyAnswer:
    type: entity
    table: survey_answers
    inheritanceType: JOINED
    discriminatorColumn:
        name: type_class
        type: string
    discriminatorMap:
        database: SurveyDatabaseAnswer
        client_text: SurveyClientTextAnswer
        client_number: SurveyClientNumberAnswer
        client_date: SurveyClientDateAnswer

    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO

    manyToOne:
        client:
            targetEntity: Entity\Client
            joinColumn:
                name: id_client
                nullable: false
                referenceColumnName: id

        survey:
            targetEntity: Entity\AbstractSurvey
            joinColumn:
                name: id_survey
                nullable: false
                referenceColumnName: id
```

and

```
Entity\SurveyDatabaseAnswer:
    type: entity
    table: survey_database_answers

    indexes:
        id:
            columns: [id, id_answer]

    manyToOne:
        answer:
            targetEntity: Entity\Answer
            joinColumn:
                name: id_answer
                nullable: false
                referenceColumnName: id
```

I update the tables this way ,and It works(has some ommited code and some doctrine functions like flush are encapsulated on another classes)

```
$updated_answer = new SurveyDatabaseAnswer();
$updated_answer->setId($result[0]);
$updated_answer->setClient($client);
$updated_answer->setSurvey($survey);
$updated_answer->setAnswer($answer);
$storage->merge($updated_answer);
$storage->flush();
```

but If I try t insert a new row

```
$updated_answer = new SurveyDatabaseAnswer();
$updated_answer->setClient($client);
$updated_answer->setSurvey($survey);
$updated_answer->setAnswer($answer);
$storage->persist($updated_answer);
$storage->flush();
```

I get this error,doctrine tries to insert and existing id

```
Type: Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException

Message: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO survey_database_answers (id, id_answer) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [7438572, 1888]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7438572' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I'm d0ing something wrong on doctrine?